# Using grep -Po to extract regex

Tags: grep

I've been struggling with "grep -Po" off and on for a couple hours.

What I would like to do is to find out how many bytes the virtual disk size is as reported by qemu-img info.

Here's example output:

```
$ qemu-img info 022eb199-954d-4c78-8550-0ea1d31111ec                                           
image: 022eb199-954d-4c78-8550-0ea1d31111ec
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)
disk size: 20G
cluster_size: 65536
```

And here's what I've been trying variations of:

```
$ qemu-img info 022eb199-954d-4c78-8550-0ea1d31111ec | grep -Po '\(([0-9]+).*\)'
(42949672960 bytes)
```

But I would just like the number. I guess I'm struggling with how to tell "grep -Po" which part of the regex I'd like extracted. I thought the "(" brackets would do that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: How about awk?  `cat text | awk '/^virtual size/ {gsub(/.*\(/,""); gsub(/ bytes.*/,"");print}'`.  Find the line matching 'virtual size', replace everything before the '(', replace everything after the ' bytes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use cut twice, for example:

```
echo "virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)"| cut -f 4 -d" "| cut -c 2-
```

First **cut** cuts (42949672960,-f4 fourth field, -d" " is the separator. The second **cut** cuts 42949672960 -c2- (cuts from second character to the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)" | grep -Po '(?<=\()[^ ]*'
```

Match on the left (the right matches to the space

```
echo "virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)" |grep -oP 'virtual.*\K(?<=\()[^ ]*'
```

Or a more rigorous match to start with the text beginning with virtual

Answer (score 1):

```
qemu-img ... | grep -Po '[0-9]+(?= bytes)'
```

This is using a zero-length lookahead [assertion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), which will match the `bytes` text but won't include it in the output (because the `-o` option was given).

Such assertions are available when the `-P` switch to `grep` is used (which directs it to use `perl`/`pcre`-like regex'es). Both `-P` and `-o` were already used in OP's question and in the title.

Answer (score 0):

echo "virtual size: 40G (42949672960 bytes)" | grep -Po '(\K([^\s]+)'